# Create disk partition after installation of system Solaris 8

Tags: partition, solaris

When I was installing the OS Solaris 8, I expected that an interface will show up to manage the disk partitions, but no interface shows that.

So my question is: is it possible to do disk partitions after I finish the installation, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The format command is used to manage partitions in Solaris.

```
man format
```

Execute `format` and select the disk to partition.  You then enter the partition number you wish to change, and alter the settings.  When you have modified all paritions, use the label command in format to write your new partition table.  After changing the partitions, you need to use `newfs` to put a new file system on the modified partitions.

This will work if you have unused space available on your disk.

If your disk has been partitioned fully during the installation of Solaris 8, your best bet is to reinstall and setup the partitions the way you want (especially if you want to modify system partitions).  Otherwise, you will need to backup any data you need to preserve, boot from CD, modify partitions, and restore from backup.